# Is it possible to implement lisp "language" in Raku?

Tags: lisp, raku

In here, interpretation of `Hello $world` per each quoting symbol I mean *language*.

```
 $world = "WΩrlδ"
"(Hell)*o $world\n"           # <--- plain (Hell)*o, resolve $world, escape \n
'(Hell)*o $world\n'           # <--- plain (Hell)*o, plain $world, escape \n
/(Hell)*o $world\n/           # <--- regexp (Hell)*, resolve $world, interpret \n
<(Hell)*o $world\n>           # <--- make list ["(Hello*o", "$world\n"]
{(Hell)*o $world\n}           # <--- syntax error, this language cant' parse it
```

So is Raku powerful enough to be able to exist in future language for something like

```
my $emacs_func = (defun perl-backward-to-start-of-continued-exp (lim)
      (if (= (preceding-char) ?\))
          (forward-sexp -1))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (if (<= (point) lim)
          (goto-char (1+ lim)))
      (skip-chars-forward " \t\f"))


$  typeof($emacs_func)
> Emacs Lisp list
```

Comment: It appears as though you're looking to *embed* a lisp-like language in Perl. Is that correct? Because there's lots of implementations of [lisp in perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=38772).

Comment: Yes, embed. By means of redefining operators so that Lisp can be freely mixable with perl and it could by executed for example, or changed or printed, ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perl 6's grammar is just a grammar written in Perl 6, and very malleable (though current implementations don't quite provide all of the specced flexibility).

So what you ask is possible in principle, but might need more care. In particular are round parenthesis perfectly valid Perl 6 syntax, and even `(defun a b)` parses as valid Perl 6. So you'd need to be /really/ careful with disambiguation rules, and it would be a huge can of worms.

It probably makes more sense to restrict Lisp syntax to some specially delimited syntactic construct (like `lisp(...)` or `q:lisp{...}`), though some amount of mixing would probably be implementable.

I'm sure that once such features are available in a compiler, we'll see a whole lot of interesting experiments, and only those experiments will show what kind of language mixing is both feasible and useful.

Answer (score 6):

[I seem to have missed the question is about Perl6, not Perl5. Leaving my answer up anyway since it might be of interest to some.]

It's my understanding that Scheme and Lisp are related. If you're ok with Scheme instead, [Inline::MzScheme](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::MzScheme) allows one to have blocks of Scheme code in Perl.

Even if you're not ok with Scheme, you could surely fork the module to edit it to use your favorite Lisp engine without too much trouble.

It's not quite what you described, but as moritz explained, what you described is impossible because there's no way to know what parts of the code should be treated as Perl code and which parts should be treated as Lisp code.

On the other handle, through the use of 5.14's pluggable token handler (used by [feature::qw_comments](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature::qw_comments) to override `qw`, for example), it should be relatively easy to do the following:

```
my $emacs_func = lisp(defun perl-backward-to-start-of-continued-exp (lim)
   (if (= (preceding-char) ?\))
      (forward-sexp -1))
   (beginning-of-line)
   (if (<= (point) lim)
      (goto-char (1+ lim)))
   (skip-chars-forward " \t\f"));
```

(Note the addition of `lisp` to your code.)

Comment: @gvalkov, The less intrusive fix would have been to add the missing "c".

Answer (score 5):

Carl Masak recently (late 2014) created [ipso, "A metacircular Lisp in Perl 6"](https://github.com/masak/ipso) that works on current Rakudo.

There will be ways it can be combined with P6 inline; please explore "slangs" for more about that, eg [a recent blog post about macros/slangs enabling recursive inlining of arbitrary langs](http://strangelyconsistent.org/blog/macros-define-your-own-literals-day).

See also Damian Conway's [Quicksort in (P6ish) Lisp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq2HkAYbG5o&t=25m37s)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, Perl6 allows for powerful, Lisp-like macros. E.g. the parser is available in the language. That allows you to implement ANY language as a sublanguage of Perl and not just as an interpreter.

In Ikegami's example he introduced the keyword `lisp(xxx)` and that would be even simpler. The lispxxx could be one single macro that parses and translates Lisp to Perl6 and returns the result, and in his example, a compiled native sub taking one argument. Though I reckon you actually need to implement the emacs Lisp functions that you use as well. Actually what would be easy to do is to address Perl6 primitives with Lisp syntax... eg. `(+ a b c d) => {quasi + a b c d}` so that your Lisp syntax has all the power of Perl6.

See http://strangelyconsistent.org/blog/macros-what-are-they-really for a light introduction to perl6 and AST.

Comment: And does Perl6 have features like Nemerle does? How hard is to change language grammar, add keywords and operators to language?

Comment: Operators may be changes and there are examples on this with functions and http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.language/2003/03/msg13957.html with Larrys answer implies there will be operator overloading with macroes as well. Many of the examples are very easy and similar (though different syntax) to what I got when I googled Nemerle.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer...

If the only thing you're interested in is ***Lisp Formatting***, then you might want to check out Raku's `Format::Lisp` module:

https://raku.land/zef:raku-community-modules/Format::Lisp
https://github.com/raku-community-modules/Format-Lisp

The ReadMe says:

*Implementing Common Lisp's (format) language for Perl 6 - Mostly because it's an interesting challenge, but partially because it offers much more powerful options than any sprintf-style formatter, including Python and Ruby's.*